# How can you add a substring inside an if statement?

Tags: c#

There is 3 category type (New Permit, Permit to Operate and Renewal) they have a reference number like 'R-662017-01' if the first letter is R its RENEWAL while for New permit its P and N for permit to operate.

how can you substring or do that in an if statement? please help :(

Comment: This is not an asp.net question; this is a language question. What language?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code snippet:

```
string input='R-662017-01';
string sub = input.Substring(0, 1);
if(sub=="R")
{
//do RENEWAL  code here
}
else if(sub=="P")
{
//do New permit code here
}
else if(sub=="N")
{
//do Permit to Operate  code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the reference number "'R-662017-01" into a switch case statement where you substring this value and do something based on what is in the substring value

```
string str = "R-662017-01";


        switch (str.Substring(0,1))
        {
            case "R": 
                // Do somthing
                break;

            case "P":
                // Do somthing
                break;

            case "N":
                // Do somthing
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this as well:

```
string input = 'R-662017-01';
if (input.StartsWith("R"))
{
//do RENEWAL code
}
else if(input.StartsWith("P"))
{
//do New permit code
}
else if(input.StartsWith("N"))
{
//do Permit to Operate code
}
```